# why can't i edit this file?

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

i'm usinng xamarin starter and i cannot design layout at xamarin studio or visual studio but i can deploy an app.
The error message is "**The layout could not be loaded: The operation failed due to an internal error: com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.hardwareConfig..... /screenorientation;Z)V.**

whether Xamarin starter or indie could not design a layout in Main.axml?
because when i using visual studio i see this message.

**"why can't i edit this file?
this project requires a xamarin business or xamarin enterprise subsciption to proceed.please visit xamarin store to learn more about upgrading your subsciption".**

help me please....thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug with the latest release of the Google SDK Tools.  See this thread for discussion of how to resolve.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/48408/warning-android-sdk-tools-rev-v24-3-4/p1

Comment: thankyou so much jason.i only update Xamarin for Visual Studio 3.11.837 without downgrade sdk i can design in main.axml.