# "Why can't I edit this file? This project requires a Xamarin Business..." when opening certain XML unrelated to Xamarin

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin

When I try to open certain XML files in Visual Studio Professional 2015 14.0.23107.0, the XML editor is a white screen with the following text:

**Why can't I edit this file? This project requires a Xamarin Business or Xamarin Enterprise subscription to proceed. Please visit the Xamarin Store to learn more about upgrading your subscription.**

These files have absolutely nothing to do with Xamarin.

Here is an image:

[Xamarin Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tE55B.png)

If I attempt to open the XML file using **Open With** > **XML (Text) Editor** I get the follow error message:

**The operation could not be completed. The parameter is incorrect.**

No matter what I try, I can't seem to open certain XML files in Visual Studio.

Is this a known bug? I tried searching for information but everything I found was in regard to Xamarin.

Comment: Can you attach a debugger and get the stack trace of the second error?

Comment: Looks like a bug... but they have reported different file extensions - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32292686/why-cant-i-edit-this-file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32292686/why-cant-i-edit-this-file/32292711#32292711

Comment: Maybe that **is** the contents of the file.   Can you open it with notepad.exe?

Comment: I saw those, but they seem to be related to the Google SDK and Android development, for which I am doing neither.

Comment: I can edit the files in notepad and various other text editors on my machine. They contain known data written by our program.

Comment: I found a work around. Edit the file so that it is no longer valid XML, open it in Visual Studio, fix the error you created, and then save the file. Visual Studio seems to remember the file and will allow you to open it in the future, despite having identical contents.

Comment: Please consider trying to raise the visibility of this problem with Microsoft. See https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/9561930-improve-the-the-parameter-is-incorrect-feature

Answer (score 0):

I contacted Xamarin and they suggested uninstalling the Xamarin Tools installed with Visual Studio 2015. This corrected the problem.